# Running packed Electron app made with Angular

Tags: angular, electron, electron-builder

I have an Electron app which is made with Angular and it works fine.
The problem comes when the app is packed as installable one with `electron-builder`.
When the app is ran after the installation it starts with a blank screen. 
In the development console I can see that it tries to load the following files from `C:\` not from `AppData\Local\..`.

- inline.bundle.js
- polyfills.bundle.js
- scripts.bundle.js
- styles.bundle.js
- vendor.bundle.js
- main.bundle.js

The angular app is build with ng-cli.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Out of interest, how did you open developer tools in production mode?

Comment: I bound it to a key combination :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by changing `<base href="/">` to `<base href="./">` and it worked for me.
Sorry for the late response.